# A way to generate a custom session ID without editing php.ini

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to create a custom session ID generator. From what I've read across the sites you can do this by manually editing PHP's settings files, however, it will not be available until I switch from my shared servers to a fully customisable one.

What i'm trying to ask is whether it's possible to specify how session IDs are generated by inputting a PHP code to a page? My intention is to use the same mechanics as the default ID generator, but use sha512 and a few custom goodies such as salt.

Comment: Why would you want this? PHP-Sessions are secure enough by default.

Comment: Is your problem to edit the php.ini file? Or that you don't have the hash installed you're looking for?

Comment: My problem is that I can't edit php.ini on a shared hosting site, but no matter, @MVS has provided me with an answer, thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you pass a string to the `session_id()` function before calling `session_start()`, you can set the session ID yourself.  For example:

```
function generate_id() {
  ...
  return $your_id;
}

session_id(generate_id());
session_start();
```

Comment: This is not compatible with [`session_regenerate_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php).

Comment: It is, though not directy. I might need to run a few tests to see whether the method I'm thinking of is worth using, but it's possible. Thank you for your concern, though.

Comment: If you pass an id into session_id and that was the ID from a previous session, would session_start continue the previous session if cookies/get/post did not any PHPSESSID data? I'm asking to see if you can pass the session id manually, instead of relying on cookies/get/post.